# How to access jQuery variable in PHP and PHP variable in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

**What I want to do:**

- I want to get a value from a select element
- And then I want the specific record from the database on the basis of that value.
- Finally, gets the record and displays it in an input field

**This is my code:**

[image]

Comment: Remember that PHP runs on the server, so sticking PHP code into your Javascript means that it won't be there once you're trying to run the Javascript - just the results of it will appear in your script, in this case there will be no output. If you want to run PHP from inside your Javascript, you'll have to call the routine on the server and process the results that are returned from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass jQuery variable to PHP as such, however you can do same thing through ajax, where just pass selected value through ajax to PHP file and get returned result display in input field

```
<script>
  $("#chooseRoles").change(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     url: 'getValue.php', 
    data: 'selectedRole='+$(this).val(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result){
       $("#userRoles").val(result);
    }
  });
});
```

PHP CODE (getValue.php);

```
$roles = Roles::find($_POST['selectedRole']);
echo $capabilities = $roles->capabilities;
```